# realizar una función sincrona

Tags: javascript

Muchísimas veces he tenido este problema en el cual debo verificar algo primero, pero como se realiza de manera sincrona, no me funciona.

En la sección de mi código, que dice: `if(matrix.length === 100)`, el for no alcanza a llenar el array `matrix`, por lo cual el `if` no tendrá efecto.

Entonces, debo usar promesas? Sé como funciona algo de su sintaxis, pero no estoy muy familiarizado con ellas, sin embargo existe algún otro mejor método?, algo como que en vez de existir un operador "if", fuese:

`when(matrix.length === 100)`, osea que esperara a que estuviera en 100 y si nunca llegara a 100 no tendría efecto, pero aún asi estaría como en estado de `"alerta"` , por si llega y así ejecutar el código.

```js
function returned(){
  var matrix = [], status = [];
  if(matrix.length === 100) {
  status.push(200); 
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) matrix.push(i);
  return status;
}

console.log(returned())
```

*PD: No me gusta depender de ningún libreria, API , etc.*

Comment: Te refieres a que si mandas llamar la función `returned()` y tu matriz aún no es 100, entonces que algo 'espere' a que sea 100 y te regrese el estatus 200?

Comment: Exacto, por eso el tema de las promesas.

Comment: Un ejemplo usando esta función donde tengas que verificar el status, y si no es 200, esperar a que sea 200 mientras tu código se sigue ejecutando?

Comment: Sí exactamente eso yikarus !!

Comment: Más bien preguntaba si no podrás proveer un ejemplo más concreto de un caso como este, donde se vea justamente cuando tu código no funciona bien porque tu matriz aún no es 100

Comment: Pues en el código que propuse, el if no tiene efecto.

Comment: Tendrías que inventar una suerte de envoltorio observable que por dentro tuviera una matriz. Este envoltorio, en la forma de una instancia de objeto, debiera soportar los mismos métodos que el array (al menos push) y forwardear el push al array que tiene dentro. Cuando hace este forward puede comprobar si la matriz alcanzó un largo y ahí gatillar una acción. Un comportamiento más completo sería que este objeto fuera capaz de notificar a otros de que se ha cumplido la condición, y que otroso objetos pudiesen suscribirse a las notificaciones de tu seudomatriz

Comment: El if no tiene efecto porque lo evalúas antes de llenar el array

Comment: Por eso, quiero que se evalue después asincronamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu código tiene un gran error de arquitectura y lógica. Nota que tu condición `if(matriz.length === 100)` debe ejecutarse **HASTA** que la matriz termine de llenarse; lo cuál no sabes cuándo sucederá.

En este caso concreto, lo mejor es refactorizar el código, y aplicar la filosofía de Hollywod "No nos llames, nosotros te llamamos" (*IoC, Inversion of control*). Primero analiza qué eventos son relevantes para un observador (*callback*), una vez ocurran estos eventos deberás informarle al observador.

En tu caso concreto sólo hay dos eventos relevantes, cuando la matriz se está llenando y cuando éste termine de llenarse.

```js
function LlenarMatriz(matriz, callback)
{
    var ac = 0
    while (10 !== ac++) {
        matriz.push(ac)
        callback("Llenando", ac)
    }
    callback("Ok")
}

LlenarMatriz([], function(evento, valor) { 
    if ("Ok" === evento) {
        console.log("[Info] Se ha terminado de llenar la matriz")
    } else {
        console.log("[Info] Se ha agregado el elemento " + valor)
    }
})
console.log("Esto se ejecuta después")
```

En el anterior código `LlenarMatriz` recibe como argumento dos valores, la matriz a llenar y el observador a informar.  En la llamada a la función `LLenarMatriz` el observador se suscribe a ambos eventos "Ok" y "LLenando".

## Utilizando promesas

El anterior código puede reestucturarse según el nuevo esquema de callbacks propuesto por ECMAScript. Aclaro que los promises son sólo una convención de callbacks.

```js
var LlenadorMatriz = (function() {
  
  class _LlenadorMatriz 
  {
    constructor(matriz)
    {
      this.matriz = matriz
    }
    
    async while(callback){
      var ac = 0;
      while (10 != ac++) {
        await (Llenador_push(this.matriz, ac).then(callback))
      }
      return this.matriz
    }
  }
  
  async function Llenador_push(matriz, elem) 
  {
    matriz.push(elem)
    return elem
  }
  
  return _LlenadorMatriz
  
}())

var llenador = new LlenadorMatriz([]);
llenador
  .while(function(nuevo) {
    console.log("[Info] Se ha agregado el elemento " + nuevo)
  })
  .then(function(matriz) {
    console.log("[Info] Se ha terminado de llenar la matriz")
  })
console.log("Esto se ejecuta antes!!");
```

El anterior código es una alternativa del primer método pero con una metodología orientada a objetos. Se ha utilizado promesas ímplicitas (Las funciones asíncronas devuelven una promesa pero con una sintaxis más amigable). No pienso explicar lo que son funciones asíncronas, ni promesas puesto el tema es demasiado amplio y no es la pregunta original del OP.

Comment: Eduen, en tu primer ejemplo, si coloco el callback("ok") antes del while, aún así funciona y eso que javascript es sincrono, entonces porqué sucede eso? es porque queda una "referencia" de la matriz?

Comment: @Eduardo Sebastian funciona pero no de la forma correcta. Si colocas `callback("ok")` antes del while, entonces el primer mensaje en la consola será `[Info] Se ha terminado de llenar la matriz` lo cuál es falso, ya que `matriz.length` sera `0` es decir no tendrá ningún elemento.

Comment: Esque esa es mi idea, que aún colocandolo arriba, se realice de manera asincrona

Comment: Ve la segunda respuesta

Comment: Auténtico, me ha servido perfecto, muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 4):

buen dia, me parece que tienes el "if" en la posición incorrecta, las promesas se usan en métodos asíncronos, este método no es asíncrono

```js
function returned(){
  var matrix = [], status = []; 
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  { 
     matrix.push(i);
     if(matrix.length === 100) {
       status.push(200); 
     }
  }

  return status;
}

console.log(returned())
```

Comment: si deseas usar callbacks o promesas para estos casos no lo recomendaria mucho.

Answer (score 4):

Mi idea es hacer una **`clase`** que extienda de **`Array`**.

A esta clase le asignamos un `handler` para que cuando llegue a tener 100 elementos se dispare:

```js
class AwesomeArray extends Array {

  constructor(...args){
    super(...args)
    
    this.originalPush = this.push

    const status = []
    
    this.handler = new Function
    
    this.push = (...args) => {
      this.originalPush(...args)
      if(this.length == 100) {
        status.push(200)
        this.handler({ status })
      }
    }
  }
}

const matrix = new AwesomeArray
matrix.handler = ({ status }) => console.log(`status: ${status}`)
for(let i = 0; i < 200; i++) matrix.push(i)
```

Comment: Tengo una duda con tu código, para qué es la parte de this.originalPush.call(this, ...args) , sé que estas llamanda al método nativo de la clase array, cambiandole el contexto con call y pasandole como argumento args, pero con qué fin ? podrías explicarmelo , por favor

Comment: Si te refieres a porqué le paso el contexto a la función handler, no es por nada en concreto, funcionaría igualmente si haces `this.handler(...args)` pero bueno, he visto ejemplos de librerías en que a sus métodos le puedes especificar el contexto con el que quieres que se llame a la función. O por ejemplo los métodos `.map`, `.reduce`, etc... Lo voy a cambiar porque creo que puede confundir más que ayudar.

Answer (score 3):

Usa el ciclo while() el lugar del for():

```js
function returned(){
  var matrix = [], status = [];
  var count = 0; //contador
  
  // mientras el tamaño de matrix NO sea 100 haga:
  while(matrix.length !== 100){
    matrix.push(i)
    count += 1; // aumenta en 1 el contador por cada repetición
  }


  //yo omitiria este if() ya que cuando sale del while es por que
  // el tamaño de matrix ya es 100    
  if(matrix.length === 100) {
    status.push(200); 
  }

  //si omite el if()
  /*status.push(200);*/

  return status;
}

console.log(returned())
```

Aun que no estoy seguro que sea lo que quieres

Answer (score 3):

En el caso del fragmento de codigo que presentas, siempre va a retornar vacio, pues el el if se ejecuta cuando aun no has completado matrix. Muchos de los metodos nativos de javascript se ejecutan de manera sincrona y en caso contrario se especifica en la documentacion que devuelven una promesa o reciben callbacks. Para este caso las funciones nativas de array que usas se ejecutan sincronos la solucion seria :

```
const returned =  () => {
    //Initialize local variables
    let matrix = [], status = [];
    //Execute the for loop
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        matrix.push(i);
    //Check the conditional
    if(matrix.length === 100) 
        status.push(200); 
    //Return value.
    return status;
}

//Show the result.
console.log(returned());
```

Solo cambiar el if de lugar y ponerlo mas abajo. Para casos mas complejos siempre es mejor usar [Promesas](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) o [async/await](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions), o usar librerias de terceros que ya hacen este trabajo por ti, y no tiene nada de malo pues lo mas saludable y como buena practica de programacion es reutilizar el codigo que esta a tu disposicion y que ademas ha sido hecho, probado, aprobado y usado por la comunidad, sin la cual nada de esto tendria sentido.
Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) y colocar valores globales para que puedas ver lo que quieras.

```js
function ejecutarCallbacks(callbackEjemplo){
 //se ejecuta una sola vez
    console.log(callbackEjemplo());

   //ejecuta nuevamente
    console.log(callbackEjemplo());
}
const matrix = [], status = [];
function returned(){

  if(matrix.length === 100) {
  status.push(200); 
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) matrix.push(i);
  return status;
}
ejecutarCallbacks(returned);
```

Otro ejemplo y me parece mejor es usar [Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)!

```js
const matrix = [], status = [];
function returned(){
  const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
   
     if(matrix.length >= 100) {
        status.push(200); 
      }else{
       for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) matrix.push(i);
      }

      resolve([matrix,status]);
    }, 5);
    
    if (!matrix) {
      reject(new Error('No existe un array'));
    }
  })
  
  return promise;
}
returned()
  .then(function() { console.log(status); return returned() })
  .then(function () {
    //console.log(matrix);
    console.log(status);
  })
```

Comment: No veo muy práctico tener que ir llamando a la función `n` veces hasta que entre al if. ¿Qué ventaja le ves a tu planteamiento respecto a mover el `if` después del `for`?

Comment: no lo dejo porque sea practico, lo dejo modo ejemplo que espera que una funcion se ejecute para ejecutar otra, la pregunta es como manejar procesos sincronos en javascript esperando el resultado de otra

Comment: Resolve sólo recibe un parámetro, el hacer `resolve(matrix,status)` el compilador/interprete obviará todos los parametros excepto el primero, es decir `resolve(matrix, ...) = resolve(matrix)`. Si quieres pasar ambos valores lo normal es devolver un arreglo u objeto `resolve([matrix,status])`

Comment: gracias @EduenSarceño no me dio error por que las variables estan globales

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que veo en tu código para que no ejecute el `if` es que tu array `matrix` está llegando a 101 y no a 100 por lo cual la condición nunca se va a cumplir. Para que el array no sobrepase el valor de 100 puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Iniciar la variable `i` del `for` en 1
2. Iniciar la variable `i` del `for` en 0 pero cambiar la condición de `<=` a `<`

```js
function returned(){
  var matrix = [], status = [];
  for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) matrix.push(i);
  if(matrix.length === 100) {
  status.push(200); 
  }
  return status;
}

console.log(returned())
```

Comment: Edité mi pregunta, realmente el enfoque de mi pregunta no es tan específico, mirala ahora, va más orientada al tema de asincronía.