# Problemas para crea un callback

Tags: javascript, callback

Hola estoy realizando una prueba sobre el uso de funciones asincronas y estamos viendo Callback, me dan el siguiente enunciado:

> Implementa la función "callback" para que reciba un número y lo
>   imprima por consola. Utiliza esa función para iterar sobre el array
>   utilizando el método forEach que tienen los mismos.

y me dan el siguiente codigo:

```
var miArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function callback(/*...*/) {
}

miArray./*...*/
```

He intentado darle solucion de multiples maneras pero no he podido, espero poder recibir ayuda, ya que me exigen una manera en particular.

Comment: ¿cuáles son las soluciones que has intentado?

Comment: espero te pueda guiar esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: Posible duplicado de [realizar una función sincrona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118053/realizar-una-funci%c3%b3n-sincrona)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo te pide que completes la función callback y el forEach que es una funcion propia de los array.

```js
var miArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

//Esta funcion recive un parametro, en nuestro caso un numero.
function callback(a) {
  //Lo imprimimos en pantalla.
  console.log( a);
}
//Con el forEach, en este caso no es necesario definir los parametros.
miArray.forEach(callback);

// Esto tambien se puede hacer

miArray.forEach( x => { callback(x) });

//Tambien puedes definir el callback dentro del for each.

miArray.forEach( x =>{ console.log(x) });
```

En esta linea `miArray.forEach(callback);` no es necesario llamar los parametros puesto que el `forEach` ya entrega uno por defecto, asi de manera interna completa la funcion :`callback(x)`.

Comment: Angel hermano, muchas gracias, probe las dos ultimas. pero no me las aceptaba parece ser que debia de ser de alguna en particulas, copie la primera y funciono a la perfeccion.

Comment: Posiblemente eran respuestas limitadas